# Ubuntu 18.04 cloud image support for ip6_tables

Tags: 18.04, lxc, ipv6

I am running an Ubuntu 18.04 cloud server on LXD/LXC.

```
# uname -r
4.15.0-30-generic

# apt-get -y install linux-image-$(uname -r)
```

It doesn't appear to have support for ip6_tables. How can I get an image with that supported?

```
# modprobe ip6_tables
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'ip6_tables': Function not implemented
```

Comment: What do you mean when you write: "on LXD/LXC"? Does that mean you are trying to run `modprobe` inside a container?

Comment: Michael, thanks for getting back. Actually I am trying to apply a netfilter firewall on the container and am getting errors that ip6_tables is not available.

Comment: You can't load modules in a container; that must be done on the container host.

Comment: Michael, the penny is dropping for me on that now duh!. How do you firewall the services in the containers ? Can containers have individual chains or must the chain on the host somehow protect the containers too ?

Comment: Containers can have their own individual firewalls, _if_ they have their own virtual network interface (they almost always do).